# Meaning of "the way in which"

Tags: phrase-meaning

what does ''the way in which'' exactly mean or equal to?

> You might not call it pacifist necessarily, but a way in which many people, not
>   necessarily following the Iraq War, but that's one example of it, came to see that war is no longer a legitimate part of the political life of a nation. It may be an existential part of it. Weapons of mass destruction could threaten us all.

Answer (score 1):

> You might not call it pacifist necessarily, but **a way in which many people**, not necessarily following the Iraq War, but that's one example of it, **came to see that war** is no longer a legitimate part of the political life of a nation. It may be an existential part of it. Weapons of mass destruction could threaten us all.

I think the part in bold can be transformed as "**how** most people came to see that war."

Answer (score 0):

This is quite difficult to explain, however i will try my best.
By saying "a way in which" the writer is expressing the way someone may see/do something etc, how they experience something.
In this case, it would be like saying 
"You might not call it pacifist necessarily, but *the way* or *how* many people came to see that war ..."

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks but really still unclear for me. what does it equal to in general not in the context.

Comment: The way in which is more-so used in 'formal' communication, its 'informal' counter part could simply be "the way" or "that"  
eg: They way in which I multiply 34 x 12 is...  
       OR: The way I multiply 34 x 12 is...  
eg: Walking is _the way in which_ I get to school  
       OR: Walking is _how_ I get to school or Walking is _the way_ I get to school

Answer (score 0):

Consider the use of the preposition **in** in the following:

**In what manner was she speaking?**
-- She was speaking very rapidly, and she was quite out of breath.

**Did the manner in which she was speaking seem normal?**
-- No, she seemed alarmed.

**which** is a proxy word for an earlier noun, to which it relates. If that earlier noun requires a preposition, as is the case with **manner**, we use the same preposition with the relative **which**.

We cannot ask:

**Manner was she speaking?**  <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

We must ask:

**In what manner was she speaking?**

We could ask:

**How was she speaking?**

"In what manner" is a circumlocution for "how".

We might use the circumlocution because sometimes **how** can imply disbelief or incredulity; we are asking for an explanation for something that seems nearly impossible:

**If you were wearing a raincoat, how did your shirt get all wet?**

**With the duct-tape over his mouth, how was the prisoner speaking?**
--His tone was very angry.
**No, I mean, how was he even able to speak?**